# Кавычки после аббревиатуры

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки, аббревиатуры

Нужны ли кавычки в подобных случаях: *ученик МОУ (")Лицей(")*, *СОУ (")Гимназия № 5(")*?

Есть ли правило, регламентирующее такие ситуации? И не нужно ли согласование: *ученик МОУ Лице**я***?

Comment: О каких правилах говорите, если известны названия фирм?

Comment: @shampar О пунктуационных. Если для вас школы - фирмы... не знаю, что добавить.

Comment: Пунктуация заложена в официальное название. Будь она трижды кривая, её как часть названия надо воспроизводить в точности.

Comment: @shampar Это ваше мнение, редакторская традиция или действующее пунктуационное правило, скажите, пожалуйста?

Comment: Поменяв в названии одну (!) деталь, вы, возможно не желая того, опубликуете правильное название, но другой фирмы. Это — мнение на основе опыта.

Comment: Да почему, правда, названия школ — фирмы?! Для меня это такая же дикость, как обезьяну помидором назвать.

Comment: Я согласен с shampar, по крайней мере - по сути. О форулировках можнно спорить, но названия фирм (любых, хоть общества охраны хомячков), предприятий, учреждений пишутся так, как они зарегистрированы. А зарегистрировать можно хоть с пятью кавычками в середине слова.  Правила на эту ситуацию не распространяются. Другое дело, что в названиях государственных (бюджетных, автономных и проч.)  стараются навести какую-то упорядоченность, но пока только стараются.

Comment: Кстати, ачто все эти лицеи перестали быть ФГУПами, ФГОУ и проч?

Comment: Для  =Артём Луговой 18 часов назад=. Слово (фирма) употреблялось как общее для всех без разбору организаций, где не вяжут веников.

Answer (score 1):

Нужны. После указания ОПФ (не важно, в полной или сокращенной форме) наименование организации указывается в кавычках:
http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/75-kav2
http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/76-kav3
Это с точки зрения русского языка.
Если Вас интересует юридическая составляющая, то в официальных документах желательно использовать наименование указанное в учредительных документах, т. к. в некоторых случаях `ООО "Название"` и `ООО "НАЗВАНИЕ"` могут считаться разными наименованиями.